# How to add a block quote inside a github-flavoured markdown list item?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown, blockquote

I would like to add a quote within a list (ordered or unordered) item. **Indentation** matters. I would like to have the quotation (blockquote) highlighting-style, not code style. Indenting the `>` sign removes the quote highlighting.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This works for me:

```
* list item 1

    > Quote (note: there must be 4 spaces before the `>`, 1-3 spaces after the `>`, and there must be blank lines before and after this quote)

    Normal, unquoted text.

* list item 2
* list item 3
```

which renders (with GitHub styling) as:

- list item 1

  > Quote (note: there must be 4 spaces before the `>`, 1-3 spaces after the `>`, and there must be blank lines before and after this quote)

  Normal, unquoted text.
- list item 2
- list item 3

---

Make sure you use:

- **four spaces** indenting your `>`
- **one to three spaces** between `>` and your quoted text
- **blank lines before and after** the quote

This also works with numbered lists, with the above representing a single list with three items.

Comment: The crucial bit is the blank line preceding the `>` blockquote indicator. Otherwise, you can indent/prefix the `>` with two spaces, and drop the blank line after the quote. See https://git.io/vM731

Comment: Is it possible to continue normal text **after the quote** to still stick to the same list item? I couldn't figure it out yet how to do it.

Comment: @Abdull, sure: just skip a line and indent your plain text to align with the `>`. I've updated my example.

Comment: @Chris, thank you very much! It's interesting that once an outline contains such an "normal text after the quote" list item, all other list items will also be wrapped in a `<p>` element (here at StackOverflow, but also at GitHub). At GitHub, this results in borked format (huge margins between list items), as their CSS rules are matching incorrectly.

Comment: @Abdull, that's [by design](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.31.2/#lists): "A list is loose if any of its constituent list items are separated by blank lines, or if any of its constituent list items directly contain two block-level elements with a blank line between them. Otherwise a list is tight. (The difference in HTML output is that paragraphs in a loose list are wrapped in `<p>` tags, while paragraphs in a tight list are not.)"